# Selecting server in JBDS (Teiid)

Tags: jboss-developer-studio, teiid

I am using wildfly 10 JBDS 10 and  and Teiid Designer 10 .when I start the default server ,it has no Teiid instance,only have overview and deployment.

But if I change my server to wildfly ,I will get the Teiid instance.

Why I am not getting Teiid instance in default server.

Is changing the default server a good method.

Comment: See if this video helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUVB1uycTks also Teiid is an overlay product on WildFly, so having by default might be superfluous many more WildFly users

Comment: JBDS 'servers' represent app servers that live on your file system-- they are just 'convenience' buttons that let you start,stop, deploy, etc from the IDE.
You can easily install another server on the File system (add on your preferred version of Teiid) and add a 'new' server in JBDS to control it.  Add a 'new' server by right-clicking in the server tab.